# Passing self reference from selected element to function in event

Tags: jquery

I don't want to invoke two times the $('#selecteShuffle')

```
function sortSelect(select) {
  select.html($('select option').sort(function(a, b){
      return a.text == b.text ? 0 : a.text < b.text ? -1 : 1;
  }));
}

$('#selectShuffle').change(sortSelect($('#selectShuffle')));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it like this -

```
$('#selectShuffle').change(sortSelect);
```

and in your function - *`this` refer's to your select*

```
function sortSelect(e) {
  $(this).html($('select option').sort(function(a, b){
      return a.text == b.text ? 0 : a.text < b.text ? -1 : 1;
  }));
}
```

Or You can also do it like this - (*without changing your current function setup*)

```
function sortSelect(select) {
  select.html($('select option').sort(function(a, b){
      return a.text == b.text ? 0 : a.text < b.text ? -1 : 1;
  }));
}

$('#selectShuffle').change(function(){
   sortSelect($(this))
});
```